# Why new line is printed when I read from file?

Tags: python

When I run this code I see new line. 
I resolved it by adding `rCourse.split()` instead of `rCourse`.
But I am still curious about why new line is printed?

test.py

```
f = open('/home/test.txt', 'r')
print "oldCourses are:"
for rCourse in  f:
   print rCourse
```

test.txt

```
course1
course2
course3
adsfgsdg
sdgsfdg
sfbvfsbv
fbf
```

oldOutput

```
course1

course2

course3

adsfgsdg

sdgsfdg

sfbvfsbv

fbf

fsbf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your lines end with the '\n' character and `print` adds another '\n'.

There are multiple ways to fix this. I like to use the Python 3 `print` function.

```
from __future__ import print_function

f = open('test.txt', 'r')
print("oldCourses are:")
for rCourse in  f:
   print(rCourse, end='')
```

Comment: Also, using Python 2.7 `print` followed by comma will omit the default new line: `print rCourse,`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have this text file:

```
$ cat test.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

If you open that and read and print line-by-line you get two `\n` for each line; one that is in each line of the file and one put there by default by `print`:

```
>>> with open("test.txt") as f:
...    for line in f:
...       print line
... 
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4
```

There many ways to manage that.

You can use `.rstrip()` to remove the `\n`:

```
>>> with open("test.txt") as f:
...    for line in f:
...       print line.rstrip()
... 
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

You can use a `,` to suppress the automatic `\n`:

```
>>> with open("test.txt") as f:
...    for line in f:
...       print line,
... 
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

In Python 3.x use the [print function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) which can also be imported in Python 2.

Cheers!

Comment: The question was not how to get rid of it, but why it's there.

Comment: @zondo: Thanks for the feedback. Fixed.